# Error "No module name 'ahocorasick'" on PyCharm while importing "contractions" package

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I installed "contractions" package through pycharm. However when I compile the following code :

```
import contractions
```

It gives me error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wayne/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/expand_contractions.py", line 1, in <module>
    import contractions
  File "/home/wayne/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/contractions/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from textsearch import TextSearch
  File "/home/wayne/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textsearch/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ahocorasick
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ahocorasick'
```

However it works when I install "contractions" package through ubuntu terminal and run the code through terminal.

But still it's not working on PyCharm.

Also "pip install ahocorasick" gives error :

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ahocorasick
```

Comment: From Pycharm's `Preferences` menu, expand `Project: MyProject > Python Interpreter` and make sure you've pointed Pycharm to your `venv`

Comment: @TayTay Yes it is. Infact there are other packages I installed through PyCharm and they work perfectly fine. There are some links related to this error but none solved my problem